# What Security issues would warrant this kind of URL linking

Tags: php, security

What are the reasons or security reasons why a URL would be linked this way

```
http://www.sampledemo.com/redirect?id=17&link=http://www.sampledemo.com/manual.php
```

instead of this way

```
http://www.sampledemo.com/manual.php
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think it has anything with security?

Comment: it looks like simple redirect script that probably counts user clicks

Comment: We are here to learn from people and often times we make assumptions based on trends, books, instruction manuals, blog posts etc. my take is probably to sanitize the URl, get info from calling server etc. but it would be niceer if you share your knowledge and experience. isn't it why we are all on SO? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it isn't being used for security purposes. It might be used for site metrics and click tracking.  It's hard to say what the `id` parameter is for. Could be something like an ID of the page being linked from.

Answer (score 2):

If the URI was properly encoded (it isn't), then the only reasons I can think of are logging the hit and/or displaying a message to the user before they click to continue.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons, but the most common one is that you want to track where you're being linked *from*.  See the `id` argument?  That very probably corresponds to the site.

Comment: Just curious; what are the other reasons?

Answer (score 0):

There is no security reason. Usually something like this is used to track, where a visitor comes from. `redirect` will evaluate the `id`-parameter, that usually specifies one concrete (registered) referer and then redirect to the target page.